# C http proxy server socket - not hitting

Tags: c, http-proxy

I am trying to understand HTTP proxy server program. I wrote a simple C based socket which sends a response to as Message received. Please find the program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h>    
#include <string.h>    
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(){
        int recvSocketFd = 0;
        struct sockaddr_in serv_input_addr;
        char inputBuff[1024];

        memset(&serv_input_addr,'0',sizeof(serv_input_addr));
        memset(&inputBuff, '0', sizeof(inputBuff));

        recvSocketFd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

        if(recvSocketFd <= 0){
                printf("\nError occurred while creating a socket\n");
                return -1;
        }

        serv_input_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
        serv_input_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        serv_input_addr.sin_port = htons(8080);
        bind(recvSocketFd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_input_addr, sizeof(serv_input_addr));

        listen(recvSocketFd,5);

        int connFd = 0;
        int n = 0;
        int client_length = sizeof(serv_input_addr);

        while(1){
                connFd = accept(recvSocketFd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_input_addr, &client_length);
                if(connFd <0){
                        printf("\nError in accepting messages from socket\n");
                        return -1;
                }

                n = read(connFd,inputBuff,1023);

                if(n>0){
                        printf("\nMessage : %s\n",inputBuff);   
                }
                write(connFd,"Message received",15);
                close(connFd);

        }
}
```

This program on running is responding properly for the below request `http://<localhost>:8080/test`.

I tried to set this as a proxy. So I tried to set this as manual proxy in Firefox as `http://<localhost>` and port as 8080.

But the request is not hitting this socket.

It would be really helpful if somebody could help me in understanding this.

Note: This is not a homework program and I am not a student. I am just trying to learn things. This statement is for our honorable disgraceful respondents.

Comment: Set server name as `localhost` in the firefox proxy setting.

Comment: Hi ROhan, I went into Network -> Settings. I selected Manual Proxy configuration and in http proxy textbox http://<localhost> and port as 8080. Is there something wrong in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-Edit:

Note the importance of checking success on *bind()*. There is various cases; where one could be that the socket is in a TIME_WAIT state. If one does not actually validate the *bind()* and abort on failure the program could possibly *seemingly* be running OK. *listen()* can be passed without error. Though on the client side Firefox most likely would report with a *refused connection* it is not a given.

---

#### URI-scheme-name

In your question you state that you have used `http://<localhost>` for proxy settings. If that is literal it will fail: You are not to include the scheme name in the proxy settings.

Note that Firefox does not validate the hostname. E.g. `a4a6®←@ł´ªĸµª5d4a"#¤&%=)(=/)=` fly by with no warnings.

[image: Proxy foxy]

If one include the scheme, `http://`, Firefox will fail to connect and one will get ***Server not found***.

---

Original answer :-)

I'll leave it here even with comment on removed parts, as someone else might find it useful. (And that I used some time on writing it up.)

---

There are some issues here. I'll take them one by one.

First fix this, then report back if you want.

#### Missing header files and wrong types

[*read()*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), [*write()*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) and [*close()*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) are defined in *<unistd.h>*, but you do not include this file. It is presumably linked in, but best to add.

`client_length` is not signed int. You can use unsigned int, but best to use *socklen_t* as is defined in manual.

*read()* returns *ssize_t*, not int. Change this one as well.

#### Lack of error checking

No error checking where it should be. Rule #1: Always check for errors! Having trouble and not validating requests is … a big no no.

[*bind()*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html), [*listen()*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html) and [*close()*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) return int. 0 is success, -1 is error. On error *errno* is set.

The manual is very clear and easy to read on this. Read it for each function you use.

Include *<errno.h>* and use [*perror()*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html).

In simplest way. Aborting and no attempt to rescue we get:

```
int res;
...

res = bind(recvSocketFd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_input_addr, sizeof(serv_input_addr));

if (res != 0) {
        perror("bind");
        return errno;
}

res = listen(recvSocketFd, 5);

if (res != 0) {
        perror("listen");
        return errno;
}

...

res = close(connFd);
if (res != 0) {
        perror("close");
        return errno;
}
```

[*write()*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) returns *ssize_t* which on success is how many bytes was written, else -1 and *errno* set appropriately.

```
res_wr = write(connFd, ...);
if (res == -1) {
        perror("write");
        return errno;
}

/* Else check if entire buffer was written, if not, act accordingly. */
```

#### Write statement

Bad *write* statement:

```
write(connFd, "Message received", 15);
```

First: *"Message received"* is 17 bytes including terminating null. If you want to write this to connection use something like:

```
const char msg_received[] = "Message received";
...

write(connFd, msg_received, sizeof(msg_received));
```

Second: This is what you pass on to the client, in your case Firefox. Firefox would in other words get the characters:

```
{ 'M', 'e', 's', 's', 'a', 'g', 'e', ' ', 'r', 'e', 'c', 'e', 'i', 'v', 'e' }
```

Third: As you promptly do a *close()* after first read/write. Firefox will most likely reply with a ***The connection was reset***. Normally you would write your *inputBuff*, and not some status message like this.

#### Print to `stderr`

As a side not: Whilst it is *fair enough* to write to `stdout` in this sample, it is a good habit to write errors and debugging data to `stderr`. Keep it as a habit. Example:

```
sz_buf = read(connFd, inputBuff, BUF_SIZE - 1)

inputBuff[sz_buf] = 0x00;

fprintf(stderr,
        "\n====================== Message (%4d) ================\n"
        "%s\n"
        "--------------------------------------------------------\n"
        ,
        sz_buf, inputBuff
);
```

Comment: First of all, I wanted to limit the code I posted to a forum so that more users will read it. Thats the reason I removed error part. I agree there is a bug in message length I changed it. I don't know how the answer you gave is related to my question. Only take away for my question was I need to pass it as a character array. If you are saying that just because my code misses the error handling part I am not able to see error. I had it in my program and it is not hitting. The request from firefox is not even hitting my socket. I hope my question is clear

Comment: Man!! You are awesome!! The mistake I did is giving it as http: // localhost. I am sorry if I used any wrong words first time. I upvoted you, Thank you so much

Comment: @RengasamiRamanujam: Glad it got solved. And, no, not wrong words, but remember that the *only* reference point given for anyone reading the question is posted code. I cleaned up the answer somewhat as previous edit (at least first part) was more meant as a comment, but became a bit long to write up down here.